# Calculate $H$ of this triangle (all sides known)

Tags: trigonometry

This might be a pretty noob question but I haven't found a good/short answer for this.

So I want to calculate the dotted line of the triangle I linked below. At this triangle are all sides know but no angle so I thought to make 2 right-angled triangles to calculate the angles.

[image]

Comment: Use the cosine rule to calculate one of the angles and then consider one of the right angled triangles.

Comment: Do you know how that looks like at my example triangle?

Comment: You can use Heron's formula to find the area. Since your dotted line is an altitude,  you can compute the area a second way to find that altitude.

Comment: The Cosine rule gives 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(A) =\frac{5^2+10^2-7^2}{2 \times 5 \times 10}.
\end{eqnarray*}
And now use the right angle triangle with $A$.

Comment: @EthanBolker is that really needed, I thought it would be a pretty simple calculations cause all 3 sides are known

Comment: @MichaelMusk I think you need that or some trigonometry or a quadratic equation as in an answer below. Take your pick for what counts as simplest.

Comment: No trigonometry or quadratics needed. Heron's formula will do as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the following segment relationship,

$$\sqrt{7^2-H^2}=10-\sqrt{5^2-H^2}$$

Square once,

$$19=5\sqrt{5^2-H^2}$$

Square again to obtain,

$$H=\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{66}$$

Comment: thanks, thats better

Comment: @MichaelMusk - No problem

Answer (score 1):

Following from Ethan Bolker's comment, you can use [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to find the area of the triangle:

$$s = \frac{5+7+10}{2} = 11$$
$$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} = \sqrt{11(6)(4)(1)} = 2 \sqrt{66}$$

Then using the formula for the area of a triangle gives:

$$A = \frac{1}{2} bh$$
$$h = \frac{2 \sqrt{66} }{1/2 \cdot 10} = \frac{2 \sqrt{66}}{5}$$

Comment: Which of these would be easier to calculate

Comment: This one. You can notice that this answer does not use any repeated squaring, and the numbers aren't too hard so you can do this using paper and pen.

Comment: Is there also a direct way to calculate angles without using H?

Comment: For that you have to use the cosine rule. You can use the cosine rule for all three angles, but you swap the sides so that $a$ and $b$ are adjacent to the angle and $c$ is opposite.

Comment: And I dont need H or 90° angle to calculate angles with cos at my triangle

Comment: You don't need to have a right angle to use the cosine rule. This also applies to the sine rule as well.

Comment: But in my Case it is more useful to calculate H at first in order to do the angles (A, B, C) then, right?

Comment: You don't need to find $H$ at all. Instead you can just apply the cosine rule.

Comment: Sry, could you please do a short example how i can find angle A, B or C.

Comment: $\cos B = \frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac} = \frac{7^2 + 10^2 - 5^2}{2 \times 7 \times 10}$, $B = \cos^{-1} \frac{7^2 + 10^2 - 5^2}{2 \times 7 \times 10} = 27.7º$ (to 3 significant figures). And now if you're going to ask me what a significant figure is, please take a look at [this page](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic-home/arith-review-decimals/arithmetic-significant-figures-tutorial/v/significant-figures).

Comment: In future, if you have any more questions about the cosine rule, the sine rule or trigonometry in general, please ask a new question detailing exactly what it is you don't understand.

Comment: And also if you had given context to your question, and said you needed to find $H$ to find the best possible way of finding one of the angles, you would have saved us a lot of time. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

We have the two equations
$$5^2=H^2+x^2$$ and $$H^2+(10-x)^2=7^2$$ With $$x=\sqrt{5^2-H^2}$$ we get
$$H^2+100+5^2-H^2-20\sqrt{5^2-H^2}=7^2$$

Comment: so i need both equations to calculate H?

Comment: I think yes, you will need two equations.

Comment: Do you know also a direct way to calculate angles without using H?